# How toInvisible Undefined last element in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, bokehjs

I have a Javascript array, full_range:

```js
const range1 = _.range(1, 10, 0.5);
const range2 = _.range(10, 100, 5);
const range3 = _.range(100, 1000, 50);
const range4 = _.range(1000, 10000, 500);
const range5 = _.range(10000, 105000, 5000);
const full_range = range1.concat(range2).concat(range3).concat(range4).concat(range5);
```

I then loop over this array and populate another array.

```js
var transY= [];
var transX= [];
for(let i = 0; i < full_range.length; i++){
    let y = getTrans(full_range[i], dampingFactor, natFreq); //returns a float
    transY.push(y);
    transX.push(parseFloat(full_range[i]));
    }
```

The result is then returned to another function where:

```js
console.log(transX); //Correct: Prints Array of 91 length (although the numbers with //decimals are at the end for some reason
console.log(transY); //Correct: Prints Array of 91 length
console.log("first");
console.log(transX[0]); //Correct: Prints 1
console.log("Last"); 
console.log(transX[-1]); //Incorrect: Prints "undefined instead of the last item

let xd = transX.pop();
console.log("xd:" + xd); //Works and correctly prints the last item in transX
```

The goal is to graph this dataset on a BokehJS graph, which does weird things when the last value is undefined.

Why is "undefined" being treated as an array element using slicing, but not when using pop()?

How would I be able to get the array without the undefined element?

Comment: "*//Incorrect: Prints "undefined instead of the last item*" it's quite correct. There is nothing at the nonexistent property called `-1` thus you get `undefined`. Same as if you tried `transX["fred"]` or `transX["seahorse"]`. "*Why is "undefined" being treated as an array element using slicing*" because JS is not Python and does not need to behave like Python. In fact, it's Python that's the odd one out - in C, C++, and Java, `foo[-1]` will not access the last element. It will do different things (like "not compile" in Java) but not what Python does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative array indexing (with bracket notation) is not supported in JavaScript. However, you can use [`Array#at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) with negative indexes.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr[-1]); // wrong
console.log(arr.at(-1)); // get last element
```

Comment: Ah I'm dumb. Too used to Python. Thanks for the help